# How to Promisify node.js net.connect (with bluebird)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'd like a Promise version of node.js function `net.connect`. The Promise should be resolved with the socket if connection is successful, rejected with error if there's a connection error and preferably it should be cancellable as well, where cancellation would stop the connection attempt.

I did a quick try myself, but have not implemented cancellation yet:

```
function connectAsync() {
    var connect_args = arguments;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var socket = net.connect.apply(this, connect_args);
        socket.once('connect', function () {
            socket.removeListener('error', reject);
            resolve(socket);
        });
        socket.once('error', function (err) {
            socket.removeListener('connection', resolve);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

However, this seems to be awfully complex for such a simple thing. Is there a better way? Has somebody already done this?

Comment: I would not recommend using a promise for this.

Comment: Agree with @BenjaminGruenbaum, you can use event handling anyway here, why you need promises? Just write connect, and catch events as you do it inside of promise.

Comment: I want to write `.then(connect()).then(doThing()).then(close())` style sequences. This seems to be standard practice for DB access where `db.connect` is promisified - this is shown even in bluebird examples. Why is `net.connect` so different?

Comment: May be i'm wrong, but all this .then() methods will call simultaneously.

Comment: So you need something else to work in such way, not promises.

Comment: If connect returns a promise, doThing returns a promise and close returns a promise, they will not be called simultaneously. Should I write an example?

Comment: To work in this way with external libraries you need to write wrappers with your promise realization. No, examples is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, writing the wrappers is not a problem - promisifying net.connect is what I asked about...

Comment: I'll post an answer next week if you're still stuck as well as why Bluebird doesn't and won't support promo sifting event emitters automatically.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'd very much like that. I currently do not see why `pg.connectAsync` is an example in bluebird documentation and yet `net.connectAsync` would not be, even though they both are very similar operations in spirit.

Answer (score 2):

All in all if you look at it directly - EventEmitters ings are a very complicated abstraction.

Promises represent sequencing operations - think of them as the assignment operator or a semicolon. Code in regular sync programming looks something like:

```
try{
    var value = foo(bar);
    log(value);
} catch(e){
    // handle error
}
```

Things run one after the other:

> 1. Enter the try block
> 2. Run `foo` with argument `bar`
> 3. Log the value unless there was an error
> 4. If there was an error, handle it.

It's like a *long single chain* of operations. A promise is exactly like this:

```
 fooAsync(bar).
 then(log).
 catch(function(){
      // handle error
 });
```

A promise is a chain. You can create several such chains, which is similar to other forms of concurrency (like threads) which represent executing a sequence of actions. It looks something like the following:

> --------------------------------+-Success------------------>
>
> ```
>                    --Error---->// might join up
> ```

On the other hand - an event emitter has no guarantees about the name or type of events it fires, the node EventEmitter has some cool features baked in (like stack traces and `error` events) but there is a much weaker convention than there is with promises - different event emitters fire different events, an event emitter can do something like this:

> ```
> ----Foo fired-+-Handler 1    ---- Bar fired-+      ---- Baz Fired-+-Handler 1
>
>               --Handler 2                                         --Handler 2
> ```

It is not a single chain - so while there have been several attempts and discussions about this - no generic way to represent promises from event emitters exists - they're simply too different in the event handling and the event name.

On the other hand - `pg.connect` takes a node style err-callback. So it's easy to promisify, those are very well specified and abide to a contract.

What you have is fine, and you can generalize it to an event emitter with two events. Remember you write this sort of boilerplate *once* and then use it all over your code :)

Comment: By "use" all over your code, of course "call" is meant not "copy" :-)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the rationale. I agree 100% about event emitters in general. However, even though complexily wrapped in an event emitter, the "connect" unix call has a single result: success or failure, so there should be no reason why net.connect shouldn't or couldn't be made in to a promise method.

Comment: And indeed, if you want to use `child_process.execAsync` on `"connect"` you get a promise - however the `net` connect has more abilities than that built in.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the two `removeListener()` lines.  Promises can only be resolved or rejected once so you don't have to worry about your events getting called again.  The promise won't change it's state once it is fullfilled.

And, I think you have a couple issues to fix:

1. `var connect_args = arguments` probably won't work since `arguments` is a funky type of temporal object.  The usual work-around is to make a copy of it's contents: `var connect_args = [].slice.call(arguments);`.
2. In this line, `net.connect.apply(this, connect_args);`, I don't think `this` will be the right value because you're inside the promise callback at that point (perhaps it doesn't matter in this particular case). It would likely be more technically correct to use `net.connect.apply(net, connect_args);` which will more directly simulate calling `net.connect(args)`.

As for the wisdom of using promises for this at all, it looks like you have a couple of opinions on the matter in the comments.

Other than removing the `removeListener()` lines of code, I don't think there's really much of a way to simplify this.  You're creating a promise to respond to two different custom conditions so you have to write the code to detect those two conditions.  No way around that.

P.S. If you don't remove the `removeListener()` lines of code, you may hav an error because you're setting up an event for `'connect'`, but doing a `removeListener('connection`).  Also, I don't know why you're passing a function to `removeListener()` because it's not the same function reference you used when the event handler was established.

Comment: Thank you for the several corrections! However, if I do not call removeListener, doesn't this mean that the promise will stay in memory and cannot be garbage collected as long as the socket is open?

Comment: @Nakedible - good point on the garbage collection - that is likely true.  A comment in your code as to why you're removing the event listener would be smart because someone like me can easily come along later and think those lines can be removed because promises are immutable once fullfilled so they are immune from multiple calls to `reject()` or `resolve()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `var connect_args = arguments;`. The `apply` method does take `Arguments` objects as well.

Comment: If your `socket` persists and you don't remove the `'error'` event listener, next time there is an error of any kind (not just on connect) that function will get called.

Comment: @Terrabits - Those listeners just call `resolve()` or `reject()` and both of those ignore being called more than once (one a promise is resolved or rejected it is latched and cannot be changed), so that isn't something you have to protect against.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions I've come up with match what you've got nearly identically:

```
p = new Promise((resolve, reject) ->
    listener = (data) ->
        try
            check_data_format(data)
        catch err
            return reject(err)
        if is_right_data(data)
            return resolve()
    ee.on("stdout", listener)
)
return p
```

and occasionally when things get more unpleasant:

```
reject_f = null
resolve_f = null
p = new Promise((resolve, reject) ->
    reject_f = reject
    resolve_f = resolve
)
listener = (data) ->
    try
        check_data_format(data)
    catch err
        return reject(err)
    if is_right_data(data)
        return resolve()
ee.on("stdout", listener)
```

I filed an issue about this (asking for documentation) [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/358) but got redirected to your question.

I've come to the conclusion that the current intersection of promises and event emitters is just ugly and I have to live with it. I've not come across any better suggestions than what we've independently invented, so if you do, please share.